# Please help me with this doubt from rotational dynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics

Torque to a magnetic field on a current carrying loop is same with respect to any point in space,is the same true for all force couples acting on any body?

Comment: I wish you had explained what exactly is your doubt and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

A pure torque (no net force) is location independent, just as if a body undergoes pure translation all points translate the same.

Also a pure torque will cause a body to rotate about it's center of mass, just as to purely translate a body you need to apply a force through the center of mass.

In general if a force is applied with a moment arm with respect to the center of mass of $\ell$ then the body is going to rotate about a point a distance $$c = \frac{\kappa^2}{\ell}$$ away from the center of mass, where $\kappa$ is the radius of gyration ( $I=m \kappa^2$).

A pure torque is a zero net force at infinity ($\ell = \infty$) which causes the rotation to be about the center of mass ($c=0$). A force through the center of mass ($\ell=0$) causes the body to rotate about a point at infinity ($c = \infty$) which is the same as a translation.

I hope this helps you understand the basics of rigid body motion.